# WPF how to get drag and drop to work with control key?

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

So I have drag and drop somewhat working in WPF. it works fine with the shift key.

However, if I use the ctrl key to start a drag operation the dodraganddrop method runs fine. But while I hold the ctrl key the cursor changes to a Drop Not Allowed Symbol and the I cannot drop the items until I let go of the control key. Why is this and how can I change it? I thought the cursor was determined by setting DragEventArgs.Effects to a DragDropEffect, but I have set it to DragDropEffectsMove and I still get the no drop allowed cursor.

```
    private void NameListView_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

      // Get the current mouse position
      Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(null);
      Vector diff = NameListViewMouseDownStartPoint - mousePos;

      if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
          (Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
          Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance)
        )
      {
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl)
            || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
        {
          DataObject do1 = new DataObject("AddedItemsFormat", _GraphViewerViewModel.SelectedAddedItems);
          DragDrop.DoDragDrop(NameListView, do1, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
      }
    }

private void NameListView_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;

}

// Moves the item to the location of the insertion mark. 
private void NameListView_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  //Drop Code. This code will not run unless the user first lets go of the control key so he can drop here

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Holding the `Ctrl` key on the keyboard during a drag and drop operation relates to copying the item and therefore you need to allow the `DragDropEffects.Copy` enumeration also.  You can allow both operations by setting this in the `DoDragDrop` method:

```
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(NameListView, do1, DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);
```

You could also use this:

```
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(NameListView, do1, DragDropEffects.All);
```

Comment: So i tried this and it didn't have any effect, but then I revised my dragdrop to 
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(AvailableSignalsListView, do1, DragDropEffects.All);

and it solved my problem. If you can revise your answer I'll give you credit since you solved my problem. I think e.Effects controls the mouse cursor type which is correct, but the actual allowing or disallowing is determined by the dodraganddrop parameter